# Can't use Bind and ConfigureConsumer together

Tags: c#, masstransit

I'm using MassTransit + RabbitMQ combo in Asp.Net Core app. The relevant configuration part below:

```
public IBusControl CreateBus(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
{
    var options = serviceProvider.GetService<IConfiguration>().GetOptions<RabbitMqOptions>("rabbitmq");

    return Bus.Factory.CreateUsingRabbitMq(cfg =>
    {
        cfg.Host($"rabbitmq://{options.Host}:{options.Port}");
        cfg.ReceiveEndpoint("ingest-products", ep =>
        {
            ep.PrefetchCount = 16;

            ep.UseMessageRetry(r => r.Interval(2, 1000));
            ep.Bind<CreateProducts>(x =>
            {
                x.RoutingKey = "marketplace";
                x.ExchangeType = ExchangeType.Direct;
                x.AutoDelete = false;
                x.Durable = true;
            });

            ep.ConfigureConsumer<CreateProductsConsumer>(serviceProvider);
        });
    });
}
```

When I run the application, I'm getting this exception:

> ArgumentException: The
>   MassTransit.RabbitMqTransport.Topology.Entities.ExchangeEntity entity
>   settings did not match the existing entity

What am I doing wrong here? Am I not supposed to configure a consumer with the `IServiceProvider` after I bind exchange to a receive endpoint? If not, then how do I configure it properly (well, I still want stuff to get injected into my consumers)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are binding the messages types to the receive endpoint that are the same as message types in the consumer, you need to disable the automatic exchange binding.

```
// for MassTransit versions v6 and earlier
endpoint.BindMessageExchanges = false;

// for MassTransit versions 7 and onward
endpoint.ConfigureConsumeTopology = false;
```

This will prevent MassTransit from trying to bind the messages types of the consumer on the endpoint.

Answer (score 1):

I spent most of my day trying to find this. In v7+ it was renamed to:

`endpoint.ConfigureConsumeTopology = false;`

Answer (score 1):

You need to disable automatic message exchange binding in order for your custom message binding to work.

```
endpoint.ConfigureConsumeTopology = false;
```

By following the [source code](https://github.com/MassTransit/MassTransit/blob/c23a7029908f38507eba0d1d9669162f1b2d9ca6/src/MassTransit/Configuration/IReceiveEndpointConfigurator.cs) on GitHub we can see that **ConfigureConsumeTopology** method obsoletes the previous methods, such as BindMessageTopics, **BindMessageExchanges**, SubscribeMessageTopics.